# How can i test my html code in Visual Studio Code ? when i click the run button it's browsing in edge to http://localhost:8080/

Tags: visual-studio-code

and then show me message can't reach that page.
this is the launch.json code:

```
    {
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "msedge",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to test the code.
I have index.html file, style.css and app.js

I see it's trying to "Launch Chrome against localhost" then what should I do to test my code if it's working?

the error message:

[image: error message]

this is the index.html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Google Maps Api</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">

    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Google Maps</h1>
    <div id="map"></div>
    
        <script defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=I HAVE A KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    <script src="/app.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

the style.css

```
#map
{
    height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

the app.js

```
function initMap()
{
    var options = 
    {
        center: {las: 38.3460, lng:-0.4907 },
        zoom: 8
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options)
}
```

I want to run it and test it like on a real website.
I have a site on wix already so I wonder if I have to test it as a real site on my wix site or I can use only the visual studio code?

I tried to follow this tutorial and at minute 13:22 he just types it and save it and it's showing google map.

on minute 5:07 when I ran it showed my Google Maps like in the video tutorial but after that it's showing me that error can't reach that page.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPhWSyRqQDA&t=801s

Comment: _"and then show me message can't reach that page"_ - what is the **actual and exact** error message, and what browser are you using? If you're using Edge do you have "Friendly" HTTP error messages disabled? Do you have an aggresively configured local firewall?

Comment: _"then what should i do to test my code if it's working?"_ - Let me ask you, what do you mean by "test my code", exactly? How much research have you done into browser-based testing frameworks and test-runners?

Comment: @Dai by testing i mean like in a real site.  the idea in this code is to display google map/s and i tried to follow this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPhWSyRqQDA&t=801s at minute 13:22 he just save it or run it and it's showing the google map.

Comment: i installed live server and now it's now showing the error but also not showing the google maps.  but it does showing me this hand on the mouse cursor like googla maps cursor but not showing the map it self.  do i need to get the api key from a billing account ? because the key i have now is from my project.